# How to create custom seekbar in android

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an application in which i want to control the lights using dimmer switch.i want to dim and full the light using this control and fet the relevant values.

So my question is Which control will be appropriate for this requirement ?

I did some research and came to know that [Seekbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) can satisfy my requirement. But how do i create custom [seekbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) like below image.

[image]

If is there any other way to achieve this, then please give me some ideas.Any suggestion and guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example is running in my apps but modify to you requirment .

```
package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,is there any other way to contact you?